# clean up the header of csv files with awk

Tags: linux, bash, shell, csv, awk

I have a bunch of csv files that look like this:

```
Time,Channel A
(s),(V)

0.00000000,0.58058560
0.00666667,0.58913630
0.01333334,0.58058560
```

And I want to transform it to:

```
Time (s),Channel A (V)
0.00000000,0.58058560
0.00666667,0.58913630
0.01333334,0.58058560
```

The units are not necessarily identical across files (i.e. there might be `(ms),(µV)` etc.)

I got as far as removing the blank line (which is always line no. 3) with `awk 'FNR!=3'` but cutting the 2nd row arguments and pasting them behind the first row fields is beyond my capacity ;(

Please help me out!
Motivation: there are lots of these files. Doing it by hand is not feasible…

EDIT:
First of all: thanks for helping me out. As there seems to be the same issue with 2 of your answers, there might be a problem in my file potentially? I suspect the empty line to somehow cause trouble?

- the shell-script gives me the error `'xpected empty line, read '`
- the perl-script *and* the awk-script give me a faulty first line:

  ```
   (V) (s),Channel A
  0.00000000,0.58058560
  ```

If it helps, [I uploaded a sample infile](https://www.dropbox.com/s/iuu0aowimchghed/infile.csv?dl=0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use perl instead

```
perl -lpe 'if($.==1){$x=<>;($T,$C)=$x=~/(\([^\)]\))/g;s/[^,]+\K,.*/ $T$& $C/;<>}' file

Time (s),Channel A (V)
0.00000000,0.58058560
0.00666667,0.58913630
0.01333334,0.58058560
```

If you have CRLF file, which it looks like you do.

```
perl -lpe 'chop;if($.==1){$x=<>;($T,$C)=$x=~/(\([^\)]\))/g;s/[^,]+\K,.*/ $T$& $C/;<>}' file
```

Comment: I'm not good at perl, so I can't really parse your answer, but what I get as a result is `(V) (s),Channel A` in the first line. thirld line is properly removed, tho.

Comment: @Paul Probs have carriage returns, I'll add an edit.

Answer (score 2):

Should you decide to stay in bash, here's a script that will perform error checking for you

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function Error() { 1>&2 echo "$@"; }

function cleanup_csv() {
    IFS=$',\r' read -a Header || { Error "could not read header"; return 1; }
    IFS=$',\r' read -a Units || { Error "could not read units"; return 1; }
    declare -r NCols=${#Header[@]}
    declare -r n_units=${#Units[@]}

    [[ $NCols -eq $n_units ]] || {
        Error "number of columns in Header ($NCols) not equal to Units ($n_units)"
        return 1
    }

    if IFS=$' \t\r' read -a words; then
        if [[ $(echo "${words[*]}") ]]; then
            Error "expected empty line, read '${words[*]}'"
            return 1
        fi
    else
        Error "could not read line 3, expected empty line"
        return 1
    fi

    local i= sep=
    for ((i=0; i<NCols; ++i)); do
        printf "%s" "$sep${Header[i]} ${Units[i]}"
        sep=,
    done
    printf "\n"
    cat
}

cleanup_csv "$@"
```

Given a file 'in' with your sample input

```
Time,Channel A
(s),(V)

0.00000000,0.58058560
0.00666667,0.58913630
0.01333334,0.58058560
```

and invoked like this

```
./cleanup_csv.sh < in
```

it produces the desired output

```
Time (s),Channel A (V)
0.00000000,0.58058560
0.00666667,0.58913630
0.01333334,0.58058560
```

I also tested it with more than two columns

```
Time,Channel A,Channel B
(s),(V),(mV)

0.00000000,0.58058560,12.34
0.00666667,0.58913630,3.1415
0.02000002,0.58058560,0.913
```

And that works as well

```
Time (s),Channel A (V),Channel B (mV)
0.00000000,0.58058560,12.34
0.00666667,0.58913630,3.1415
0.02000002,0.58058560,0.913
```

**Edit**:

I updated the reading and detection of the empty line because your input has Windows style line endings (CRLF).  You can see the carriage return using `od -xc`.  I went ahead and added tab characters to the set of characters to use as field separators (IFS), I then look to see if any non-whitespace characters are left after `echo`.

Here's the hex dump of the input I tested (with added space and tab in the 'empty' line):

```
$ od -xc in.csv
0000000    6954    656d    432c    6168    6e6e    6c65    4120    0a0d
          T   i   m   e   ,   C   h   a   n   n   e   l       A  \r  \n
0000020    7328    2c29    5628    0d29    200a    2009    0d20    300a
          (   s   )   ,   (   V   )  \r  \n      \t          \r  \n   0
0000040    302e    3030    3030    3030    2c30    2e30    3835    3530
          .   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ,   0   .   5   8   0   5
0000060    3538    3036    0a0d    2e30    3030    3636    3636    3736
          8   5   6   0  \r  \n   0   .   0   0   6   6   6   6   6   7
0000100    302c    352e    3938    3331    3336    0d30    300a    302e
          ,   0   .   5   8   9   1   3   6   3   0  \r  \n   0   .   0
0000120    3331    3333    3333    2c34    2e30    3835    3530    3538
          1   3   3   3   3   3   4   ,   0   .   5   8   0   5   8   5
0000140    3036    0a0d    2e30    3230    3030    3030    3230    302c
          6   0  \r  \n   0   .   0   2   0   0   0   0   0   2   ,   0
0000160    352e    3038    3835    3635    0d30    300a    302e    3632
          .   5   8   0   5   8   5   6   0  \r  \n   0   .   0   2   6
0000200    3636    3636    2c39    2e30    3835    3139    3633    3033
          6   6   6   6   9   ,   0   .   5   8   9   1   3   6   3   0
0000220    0a0d    2e30    3330    3333    3333    3633    302c    352e
         \r  \n   0   .   0   3   3   3   3   3   3   6   ,   0   .   5
0000240    3938    3331    3336    0d30    300a    302e    3034    3030
          8   9   1   3   6   3   0  \r  \n   0   .   0   4   0   0   0
0000260    3030    2c33    2e30    3835    3139    3633    3033    0a0d
          0   0   3   ,   0   .   5   8   9   1   3   6   3   0  \r  \n
0000300
```

Comment: This looks like both a good bash solution and a good illustration why it's worth moving to a better language than cramming stuff into bash :)

Comment: Indeed works for me, and I like the script for the error-checks. I'll keep it as a separate solution in my directory. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F , -v RS='\r\n' 'FNR == 1 { x = $1; y = $2 } FNR == 2 { print x " " $1 "," y " " $2 } FNR > 3'
```

A brief explanation: `awk` accepts logical expressions as range patterns (anything in scope can be used,) hence `FNR == n` means simply that the pattern applies to line number *n* in the current file; the last pattern applies to everything *after* line #3; omitting the action means to simply print the input as read.  Thus, lines #1 and #2 are treated specially, each according to its own meaning, and line #3 is ignored, as there's no matching pattern for it.

*UPDATE*: Edited to set `RS` (record separator) as per @123's suggestion.  An alternative way would be to include it in the script itself, possibly along with `FS` (field separator,) like this:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=","; RS="\r\n" } FNR == 1 { x = $1; y = $2 } FNR == 2 { print x " " $1 "," y " " $2 } FNR > 3'
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: this solution, too, gives me a faulty first line, which - I reckon - also is caused by carriage returns (see perl-answer or bash-answer). *But* I'll give you this: if this would work, I would love it, because I seem to understand what it does, just from looking at it! ;)
could you please try to fix it?

Comment: @Paul Just add a flag to set `RS` as `\r\n`, ie `awk -vRS="\r\n" -F, 'yadayada' file`

Comment: @Paul I was afraid it might fail the same way.  It should be possible to fix it -- for one thing, you may try @123's suggestion; failing that, could you post a hexdump of the first several lines of your text file, e.g. `cat file.txt | head -n 5 | hexdump -C`

Comment: Got it, should be fixed now.  As mentioned in other comments, the *issue* was <CR><LF> (DOS-style) line termination.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
awk 'BEGIN{
           FS=OFS=","
           }
     FNR==1{
           for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) l1[i]=$i
           }
     FNR==2{
           for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) l2[i]=$i
           }
     FNR==3{
           s=""
           for (i=1;i in l1 || i in l2; i++)
               s=s ? s OFS l1[i] " " l2[i] : s l1[i] " " l2[i]
           print s    
           }
     FNR<=3{ next }
     1' file
```

Prints:

```
Time (s),Channel A (V)
0.00000000,0.58058560
0.00666667,0.58913630
0.01333334,0.58058560
```

Comment: Think if it is that many line it's probably better suited to being in a file instead of quotes.

Comment: weirdly, same issue here as with @123 s answer (the perl way).
the output is `(V) (s),Channel A` for line 1. seems to be a problem with my csv-file?